# Formula to count the number of holidays between 2 dates in excel

Tags: excel, datetime, worksheet-function, excel-formula

Lets say I have a named range of dates that are holidays.  This range is called 'holidays'.  Is there a formula in Excel I could use to count the number of holidays that fall between 2 dates?

e.g. holidays = 7/3/2011, date 1 = 7/1/2011, date 2 = 7/7/2011: this formula calculates 1.

Edit: it seems the function `=NETWORKDAYS` gets me part of the way there, but as Excellll points out it only works if the holidays fall on weekdays.

Comment: NETWORKDAYS is only helpful if all the holidays fall on work days.

Comment: @ Excellll Thanks for the tip.  `NETWORKDAYS` works for my purposes right now, but doesn't solve the overall problem.

Comment: @Excellll: Depends what country you're in. For example, in Canada, when a holiday falls on a weekend, you get the following Monday off. In Denmark, you lose the holiday. So `NETWORKDAYS` is useful in Canada, but not in Denmark. Quite a political worksheet function...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you also have ranges named "date1" and "date2" this will work.  It's inclusive, e.g., it will count New Years Day if date1 = 1/1/11.  Remove the "="s if you don't want that.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((holidays>=date1)*(holidays<=date2))
```

Answer (score 0):

With the following formula you can get it.
NETWORKDAYS.INTL(start_date, end_date, [weekend], [holidays])
Use "0000000" including semicolons, to define weekend is none, then if desired any special weekend not on the options can be defined by specifying the desired weekend days as holidays.

Comment: Worth mentioning that this function is available from [Excel 2010 onwards](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/NETWORKDAYS-INTL-function-a9b26239-4f20-46a1-9ab8-4e925bfd5e28?ui=en-US&rs=en-IE&ad=IE).